# Convert HTML text with image attachment into NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting following from the API:

```
 "<p>The message will be &ldquo;Check out This app. I really think you&rsquo;ll relate to this.<img alt=\"smiley\" src=\"serverURL/regular_smile.png\" style=\"height:23px; width:23px\" title=\"smiley\" /></p>
\n"
```

Now I want to convert it to NSString. I have tried following but it is not returning me the Image.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *txtToShare = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:    [[dict valueForKey:@"description"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                                                                                options:@{     NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType
                                                                                                               } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

Note: Here [dict valueForKey:@"description"] contains the Html text that I have written above

Output : The message will be “Check out This app. I really think you’ll relate to this. regular_smile.png

How to get the image also?

Comment: what is dict tell me

Comment: Dict contains the HTL text that I have mentioned above

Comment: Without an absolute URL to the image, it's not going to work.

Comment: I am getting the server URL in the img tag

Comment: @SwatiGupta you need a complete URL for retrive a image only name you can not get image

Comment: @himanhu Yeah I am getting the complete URL in this.. Before the image name there is complete URL of server. In  src=\"serverURL/regular_smile.png\ instead of serverURL there is the complete URL of server.